# custom fields become unavailable after a period of time

Tags: custom-fields

I have created some custom fields to collect size data as part of an event registration form. When I first create the fields I am able to include them in a profile and use them on the form. At some point though the profile becomes unable to display them and nothing appears.
A regular profile preview just shows an empty box, but if I try to preview a single field in the profile then I see the message "This CiviCRM profile field is view only".
[image]

However, the field is most definitely not view only:
[image]
[image]

I have not found any way to make the fields display again. If I create new ones and use them, they will work for a while and then stop.

The further mystery is how they could be broken after a time? A scheduled job? Most of the enabled tasks are "always" and so I would not expect the form to work very long at all (cron runs every 10 minutes on this site). I wonder about the "clean-up" task since it runs hourly, but I'm at a loss to imagine how that would affect custom fields.

Any thoughts folks?

Running 5.31.1 on Wordpress 5.5.3

Comment: Is it similar to this? https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1984 or https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37652/custom-fields-sometimes-missing-from-profile-until-flushing-caches/37654#37654

Comment: @Demerit, those certainly look related, but clearing the cache has not helped. Following those threads I did find a comment that suggested enabling "CiviCRM: access all custom data" for all users. I did that and it started working again. However, that leaves open the question of why it worked for a time. And also why they wouldn't work even for admin.

Comment: The answer to "why it worked for a time" and then "wouldn't work even for admin" - if Demerit is right, then that issue was related to caching - i.e. it was delivering code cached for the wrong role. BTW - I'd post your solution as an answer so that others can try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, the answer was simply to enable "CiviCRM: access all custom data" for all users in Administer->Users & Permissions->Permissions->WordPress Access Control.

I am unclear whether this presents a data risk. The wording of the permission makes it feel a bit like this, but I guess if a user only has limited access by context then it isn't an issue. I am fervently hoping this is so.

The reason it appeared to work at first was related to browser and server caching. As soon as the caches cleared it failed.